# Merge operation on two small unsorted arrays to produce one big sorted array

Tags: arrays, function, sorting, merge, time-complexity

I was asked a question recently in an interview.
We are given an array A of size `n+m` with first `n` places filled with elements in random order (and m empty places at the end). Also, we have an array B with `m` elements in random order.
Write a merge function so that array A is filled with (n+m) elements in sorted order.
I was able to give a `O((n+m)log(n+m))` solution.
Is there a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**NO** there's no better solution to that. 
Let `t = max(m,n)` then the complexity is `O(tlog(t))`.
 How do we go on to prove there's no better solution ?
Will if there was a better solution to this problem when **nothing is known about the data**, then given any array of size N `(big enough)`, we could split it to `n`, `m` arrays and sort in less than `Nlog(N)`.

Comment: ...and it has been proven that sorting in less than `N log(N)` is not possible unless we have prior knowledge about the data, right?